# JMeter doesn't refresh parameters if the previous was 0

Tags: loops, jmeter

I am reading parameters from csv file and with While loop running through the list. Inside my test plan I am reading the output with JSON Path Extraction. One of the parameters is saying there are 7 items (DeedIDs_matchNr=7) [image]and then I am adding the loop to call each one of the parameters with Counter and ID for a specific call. [image]. This works as you can see above. I got 7 items and it created 7 calls. Move next to next item in csv. This item has DeedIDs_matchNr=0 so it doesn’t enter the loop and moves forward. [image]In the next item DeedIDs_matchNr=2, but it doesn’t enter the loop.[image] It looks it hold the previous DeedIDs_matchNr=0 somehow in memory and doesn’t reads the real parameter correctly. Loopcontroler config: [image]Any ideas and work around? See screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use Loop controller to loop through array of variables, there's a dedicated controller - the [ForEach controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller):

> A ForEach controller loops through the values of a set of related variables. When you add samplers (or controllers) to a ForEach controller, every sample (or controller) is executed one or more times, where during every loop the variable has a new value.

After the introduction, just put in `Input variable prefix` field `DeedIDs`
and in `Output variable` field write variable name as `currentDeedID` and use it inside loop to get current value `${currentDeedID}`